# Generate ANF equation?

Tags: s-boxes, threshold-cryptography

Given an SBox, how can I generate its component equations (in ANF)?

given in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form

For example, let's say I have this SBox:

$$\{1, a, 4, c ,6 ,f ,3, 9, 2, d, b, 7, 5, 0, 8, e\}$$

Comment: Why this answer did not satisfy you? [Generate ANF from SBox](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47957/18298)

Comment: Write the Sbox as columns multiply with $M_k$ and from $y_i$ as the rows of the final matrix. The answer contains the entries of the columns, too.

Comment: Stop me if I'm wrong, but I think that the linked [wikipedia article as it stands now](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Algebraic_normal_form&oldid=974812611) oversimplifies when it states _"two equivalent formulas will convert to the same ANF"_; that's for a stated order of the input variables, which is not trivial in the context.

Comment: I've posted a sageMath answer to the linked question. It may help to you. Closing as dupe.

Comment: @kelalaka      answer explained in Generate ANF from SBox  is really nice but when i applied the same method on other SBox the required equation is not coming. I just changed SBox matrix and multiply it with given Mobeius matrix. the matrix which is coming from that I made ANF equations row wise. But the required equation is not matching.

Comment: Well, stick with the SageMath. It is mostly implemented by the academicians and they clearly test it.

Comment: @mahimabhatnagar Given that your question is no longer "How to get the ANF description from the table" but rather "how to apply a specific method to my sbox and why doesn't it work", I suggest you make a new question that can receive more specific and helpful answers. Please don't forget to link to the relevant methodology Q&A and tell us how and where exactly (as precisely as you can) it seems to have gone wrong with your application.