# Problems on ANF equation?

Tags: s-boxes, threshold-cryptography

I tried to solve SBox as given in [this link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/generate-anf-from)

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1109/tifs.2019.2957974) SBox. In this on page no.4 the correct equation of given SBox is mentioned. I am not getting how to design ANF equation as given in paper.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kelalaka      I given paper refernce which I am trying to implement.

Comment: @kelalaka      How can I ask directly to them....???

Comment: @kelalaka       no email-id information is given.  If you get answer then please tell.

Comment: Here the original article in the [IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8924680) and [research gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337774876_Threshold_Implementations_of_GIFT_A_Trade-off_Analysis). The rest is google.

Comment: For the love of God, please typeset, do not post text as images.

Answer (score 3):

Using the S-box package of SageMath used

```
S = SBox(1, 10, 4, 12, 6, 15, 3, 9, 2, 13, 11, 7, 5, 0, 8, 14);

f0 = S.component_function(1)
f1 = S.component_function(2)
f2 = S.component_function(4)
f3 = S.component_function(8)

print ( "y0 = ", f0.algebraic_normal_form())
print ( "y1 = ", f1.algebraic_normal_form())
print ( "y2 = ", f2.algebraic_normal_form())
print ( "y3 = ", f3.algebraic_normal_form())
```

> Return a Boolean function corresponding to the component function $b\cdot S(x)$.

and the output
\begin{align}
y_0 &=  x_0 x_1 + x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 1\\
y_1 &=  x_0 x_1 + x_0 x_2 + x_0 + x_2 + x_3\\
y_2 &=  x_0 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_3 + x_1 + x_2\\
y_3 &=  x_0 x_2 x_3 + x_0 + x_1 x_3\\
\end{align}

The blow the result of the article

\begin{align}
s_0 &=  1 + a + b + ba + c + d \\
s_1 &=  a + ba + c + ca + d\\
s_2 &=  b + c + da + db + dcb\\
s_3 &=  a + bd + dca\\
\end{align}

And the result form [Conchild](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84298/18298) code \begin{align}
y_0 &= 1 + x_0 + x_1 + x_0*x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\
y_1 &= x_0 + x_0*x_1 + x_2 + x_0*x_2 + x_3\\
y_2 &= x_1 + x_2 + x_0*x_3 + x_1*x_3 + x_1*x_2*x_3\\
y_3 &= x_0 + x_1*x_3 + x_0*x_2*x_3\\
\end{align}

Martin R. Albrecht [provides](https://martinralbrecht.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/20130606_-_algebra.pdf) another method with SageMath

```
from sage.crypto.sbox import SBox

S = SBox (1, 10, 4, 12, 6, 15, 3, 9, 2, 13, 11, 7, 5, 0, 8, 14)
P.<y0 ,y1 , y2 ,y3 ,x0 , x1 ,x2 ,x3 > = PolynomialRing ( GF (2) , order ='lex')
X = [x0 ,x1 ,x2 , x3 ]
Y = [y0 ,y1 ,y2 , y3 ]
S. polynomials (X=X , Y=Y , degree =3 , groebner = True )
```

The result is compatible with the article but the $y_i$'s reversed.

```
[y0 + x0*x1*x3 + x0*x2 + x3,
 y1 + x0*x1*x2 + x0*x2 + x0*x3 + x1 + x2,
 y2 + x0 + x1*x3 + x1 + x2*x3 + x3,
 y3 + x0 + x1 + x2*x3 + x2 + x3 + 1]
```

Comment: I've posted this answer as two show that there is a different result with sageMath and the article. If there is a real answer, they can use these equations, freely.

Comment: then can you suggest what should I do now because I checked this with other  SBox table also of different algorithm it is happening with that also.  Is Mobius Transformation method is not applicable to  all SBox ??

Comment: I've not applied Mobius Transformation but the results should be identical. Why don't you post your calculation code instead of giving only the result? One cannot reproduce them by looking at the input and the result.

Comment: @mahimabhatnagar, please post your detailed calculations/code given that kelalaka has spent so much effort trying to help you

Comment: @kelalaka       I didn't understand the concept  of ANF equation so I have not written any code I am solving it manually

Comment: I've e-mailed the SageMath Sbox authors. With PRESENT SBox article. I've tested that sageMath doesn't produce the same, send the results, too.

Comment: @kelalaka      Thank You for trying to make me understand this but the mathematical concept behind it seems to be very tedious task.

Comment: @kelalaka in Boolean functions, component typically means linear combination of outputs (in contrast to coordinates - single output bits). E.g. component_function(3) return XOR of two least significant bits, not the third bit.

Comment: @Fractalic Great, That is solved all the issues. Thanks a lot. Corrected both answers.