# Algebraic Normal Form of a function in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{n})$

Tags: finite-field, s-boxes

Consider the function $f(x)=x^{2k+1}$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{n})$ for $n$ odd and $\gcd(k,n)=1$, which is differentially 2-uniform function.

For $n=3$, $k=1$, I want to find the [Algebraic Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) of the function. Is there a  way?

Comment: Please revise your question and explain more about the concept of ANF or make a link for this subject. Tell more about the application of ANF in cryptography and using examples, clear your questions for users. In fact, to receive a good answer please ask your question properly. Thanks

Comment: Anything wrong with the basic: assume a reduction polynomial for $\operatorname{GF}(2^n)$, use it to explicitly compute $f(x)$ as an $n$-bit bitstring for the mere $2^n$ values of $n$-bit bitstring $x$, makes that $n$ Boolean functions for $n$ Boolean arguments, find the ANF of each using [some systematic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form#Recursively_deriving_multiargument_Boolean_functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have $n=3$ output bits, each of them has its own ANF. Here's how to compute it with SageMath:

```
sage: from sage.crypto.sbox import SBox
sage: n = 3; k = 1
sage: F = GF(2**n)
sage: s = SBox([(F.fetch_int(x)**(2*k+1)).integer_representation() for x in range(F.order())])
sage: [s.component_function(2**i).algebraic_normal_form() for i in range(n)]
[x0 + x1*x2 + x1 + x2, x0*x1 + x0*x2 + x1, x0*x1 + x2]
```

This gives ANFs in order from least significant bit to most significant bit (this is defined by SageMath's convention for fetch_int/integer_representation).

In each ANF, the variable order is similar: x0 is the least significant input bit.

Comment: There is a minor typo at line 2 (`sage: F = GF(2**n)` should be in a new line).

Comment: Anyway, @Fractalice, I could not understand in which part did your code use the information that $\gcd(k, n) = 1$. Did I miss something?

Comment: ANF can be computed for any Boolean function (i.e., 1-bit output). I suppose $gcd(k,n)=1$ is needed for the big (n-to-n) function to be a bijection. Even if it's not, the ANFs of its bits still exist.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @fgrieu the ANF is a multivariate polynomial representation. Usually over the binary base field, so $n$ binary variables are obtained. I suppose if $n$ is composite, it can also be defined over $GF(2^m)$ where $m|n,$ and $m>1$ but see no specific advantage to doing so.

There are two explicit answers related to the suggestion in the comment in the question below:

[https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/generate-anf-from-sbox/47959](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/generate-anf-from-sbox/47959#47959)